# Extract a property from JSON output then pass on a socket

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, information-extraction

The following code is written in a node server, using a monitoring module that meters properties of a function. My problem is I want to **extract one of the properties out of a JSON output** then pass it to a socket.

meter is a function:

```
stats.meter('reqPerSec').mark;
```

Print out in JSON format every second:

```
setInterval(function() {
    console.log(stats.toJSON());
}, 1000);
```

The output:

```
{
   reqPerSec:
   { mean: 0,
     count: 0,
     currentRate: 0,
     '1MinuteRate': 0,
     '5MinuteRate': 0,
     '15MinuteRate': 0
   }
}
```

For example I want the value of `mean` and put it in a `socket.emit`.

```
socket.emit('monitoring', /*value of mean*/);
```

Debug of socket should be like `"args":[0]` is the value of mean which is 0:

```
{"name":"monitoring", "args":[0] }
```

I am not sure how to extract, it should be something like

```
function extractData(data) {
    data.reqPerSec.mean;    
}
```

Comment: Yes, that should work. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this](https://github.com/felixge/node-measured/blob/master/example/http_requests_per_second.js) example, you can get mean value like this -

```
var tmp = collection.toJSON();
console.log("mean = "+tmp.http.requestsPerSecond.mean);
```